# Javascript block won't run after update panel postback, more complicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I'm working on usercontrol called 'TimePicker',

This usercontrol utilizes the jquery timepicker, and wraps it to make it simple to use in asp.net.

I'm binding the jquery timepicker to a textbox using a simple script:

```
$('#<%= timepicker_textbox.ClientID %>').timepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        __doPostBack('<%= timepicker_textbox.ClientID %>', '');
    }        
});
```

I also chose to put this textbox inside an update panel, in order to avoid full page refresh after that the user chose a time and caused a postback.

The problem is that after that updatepanel reloaded, any script in the page is not running again, and therefore the jquery timepicker is not applied to the textbox.

I managed to fix this by adding the following code:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(<%= timepicker_textbox.ClientID %>_onControlLoad());
});


function <%= timepicker_textbox.ClientID %>_onControlLoad()
{
    $('#<%= timepicker_textbox.ClientID %>').timepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            __doPostBack('<%= timepicker_textbox.ClientID %>', '');
        }        
     });
}
```

This causes the function to be registered and then run again on each partial postback.

The problem is that this fixed the problem only for this specific timepicker, 
and not for any other elements in the same page!

This is major issue to me, since I'm having more than one timepicker inside a page, 
And when choosing time on one timepicker, the others aren't working...

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Eitan.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Updatepanel in the page changes the Id of the controls and jquery `document.ready` event did not get called  proerly,
you can read more from here-

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article471-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-updatepanel.aspx

[jquery with update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406145/jquery-with-update-panel)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add class="timepicker" to any text box you want the functionality on, and then use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            __doPostBack($(this).attr('id'), '');
        }        
     });
});
```

In general, learn to get away from driving client side behavior from the server because that mentality doesn't jive with jQuery's extremely simple select/add behavior paradigm.  The whole update panel / postback thing is really old school as well, but if you must use that, you'd have to register the function I showed above with `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest` like you were doing.  Or just put the `$(document).ready` inside the update panel, that might work too.

Comment: This might seem a little tongue in cheek, but basically if you're using `UpdatePanel` a lot, I would suggest going to ASP.NET MVC.  It only takes a couple of weeks to learn it and it gives you so much more freedom to leverage the power of frameworks like jQuery and knockout.  I gotta go to a meeting but I'll add another comment on alternatives inside ASP.NET Forms a bit later.

Comment: So the alternatives to `UpdatePanel` without moving away from ASP.NET Forms are basically to use client side templating.  Though as this question and answer indicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182581/alternatives-to-asp-net-ajax-4-0-templates, the experience is not nearly as smooth as with jQuery templates and/or Knockout JS. That answer gives good links on integrating jQuery into Forms, but I will leave a warning that it's not as intuitive as doing so in MVC.